# read.table in R "line x did not have p elements"

Tags: r, read.table

1. How do I attach a file to this question?
2. I'm trying to import a very big table (2929 lin, 24 col) to R using

```
data<-read.table("Stranding_YS_18R.txt",head=T,sep="\t")
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :  line 93 did not have 25 element
```

I've tried using a csv file with `read.csv` but that doesn't allow me to do other things I need to do later on. I've also tried using my text file with `read.table` and `fill = T` and although it opens, only 1104 lines are there. When trying to use `sep=SEPATATOR` or `sep='', strip.white=T, as.is=T` the table isn't read either.

This is what line 93 looks like:

[image]

```
    Year    DATE    Month   Beach Survey    Beach driving?  Live/Dead   Quantity    Age class   Sex Latitudey   Longitudex  Site    Distinct locations  How many seals at that 1 location   Province    Subarea (75 m sections) Coast Type  Field no.   Accession no.       Alternate no.   Staff/Agents

92  2016    08/08/2016  8   yes yes 0   1   A   M   33°42'03.2"S    26°01'57.1"E    Sunday's River Mouth to Woody Cape      NA  EC  9   east        N5087                   

93  2017    26/01/2017  1   yes yes 0   1   SA  ?   33°42'03.2"S    26°01'57.1"E    Sunday's River Mouth to Woody Cape      NA  EC  9   east    2017/N14    N5288                   

94  2017    26/01/2017  1   yes yes 0   1   SA  ?   33°42'03.2"S    26°01'57.1"E    Sunday's River Mouth to Woody Cape      NA  EC  9   east    2017/N15    N5289
```

I've tried to clean it up so it would open but then get this message and only have 1950 values.

```
> data<-read.table("Stranding_YS_18R.txt",head=T,sep="\t")
Warning messages:
1: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
2: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns
```

Comment: Could you post line 92-94 in plain text?

Comment: It is strange, that you assume there to be 24 columns whilst until line 93 R assumes there are 25 columns. Also your screenshot shows less then 24 columns. Try to open this file not with Excel but with a .txt editor in RStudio and carefully inspect, where there might be a tab `\t` hidden that looks just like a space ` `. Then copy those lines *as code* in youre question.

Comment: I agree with precedent comment, check in your `.txt` that there is not a hidden character in the last column. It would be difficult to help without the file otherwise

Comment: Hi @Bernhard, I've updated the question according to what you mentioned above.

Comment: How many columns are you reading? The second sentence in your question says 22, but R seems to think there are 25. Try setting `nrows=25` to read the first 25 lines and make certain that the column names are correct and line up with the right values. Also try `quote = ""` so R does not get confused by the Lat/Long designations.